# Assistance/Feedback on Python Program

Tags: python

I was just practicing Python and was answering this question:

**Info:** There is a sequence obtained by summing the squares of the digits of a
number repeatedly. If the sequence converges to 1 in fewer than 15 steps,
this number is considered a happy number.

**Question:** Make a program that allows the user to enter a number and it will tell them if the number entered is a happy number or not. The user should be able to keep entering numbers until -1 is entered to quit the program.

I have tried this question but there is an error saying

`File "string", line 43, in fragment`

`TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable`

I know that the error is `sequence_num += int(num[i]) ** 2` I do not understand why because before that, I converted num into a string, then since `(num[i])` is in brackets, the program should run that first then afterwards, convert it into an integer. Any idea why this is happening and/or how I can fix it. Thanks guys.

```
#Constant to determine if number is happy
MAX_STEPS = 14
#Constants to signal end of sequences or program
END_SEQUENCE_NUM = 1
END_PROGRAM_NUM = -1
#Variable to count number of steps and digit number
steps = 0
i = 0
#Variable for sequence number
sequence_num = 0

#Loops until user inputs -1
while True:
#Gets values from user
    num = input("\nPlease input a number: ")

    #Checks if user entered -1 to end program
    if num == END_PROGRAM_NUM:

    #Ends program
    break

#Checks if user inputted a number besides -1
    else:

#Loops until the sequence converges to 1 or number of steps is greater than 15
        while num != END_SEQUENCE_NUM and steps < MAX_STEPS:
#Counts number of steps
            steps += 1
#Concatenates user's number into a string
            num = str(num)

#Gets number of digits of user's number
            num_digits = len(num) 

#Squares each digit and adds the product
        while i != num_digits:
            sequence_num += int(num[i]) ** 2
            i += 1

            num = sequence_num

#Checks if number is happy
if num == END_SEQUENCE_NUM:
    num_type = "happy"

else:
    num_type = "not happy"

print "This is a", num_type, "number."
```

Comment: `num` isn't guaranteed to be a string. If that first `while` loop doesn't run, `num` stays an `int`.

Comment: The first while loop has to run because true is always true. Therefore, unless -1 is entered, the loop will run.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the second `while` loop.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, any idea how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is a little complex. Break it up into simple functions and use `for` loops. Python lets you iterate easily over lists and strings with `for` loops:

```
def squared_digit_sum(number):
    total = 0

    for digit in str(number):
        # `digit` is a string, so convert it into a number using `int()`

        ...
```

From there, you just need to loop 15 times and see if the number converges within those 15 iterations:

```
def is_happy(number):
    for i in range(15):
        number = squared_digit_sum(number)

        if number == 1:
            return True

    # The loop ended and `number` isn't 1
    return False
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Although, I haven't learned 'def', 'return' yet so is it possible that you show me the code in just loops? I'd appreciate it so much!

Comment: @JoshuaCunningham: Start by getting rid of the `while` loops and counter variables. Just iterate over the digits in your number using `for digit in str(num):`

Comment: Can you show me please? Sorry I am new to repetition and need to see it visually before I fully understand. Again thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is: pay attention to types.

Sometimes you want that num variable to be a number (when you compare it to those constant numbers for example) and sometimes to be a string (in order to slice it or get it's len). Also note that using input will give you a number assuming you're using python 2.x (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), usually raw_input is recommended (you will always get a string, no eval http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Maybe printing the type help you debugging:

```
print type(num)
```

Happy learning.